# JavaScript: How to count repetitive letters in a string and output the numbers right after?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to display an output like this `a3b2c4d3` for a string `aaabbccccddd`.

I tried the code below but didn't get the desired result.

```js
var countLetters = "aaabbccccddd";
console.log("countLetters.length --->" + countLetters.length);
var countNumberLetter = 0;
var i;
var a;

for (i = 0; i < countLetters.length; i++) {

  if (countLetters[i] == countLetters[i + 1]) {
    countNumberLetter = countNumberLetter + 1;

  }

}

console.log("countNumberLetter--------->" + countLetters[i] + countNumberLetter);
```

Comment: and why CSS/HTML ?

Comment: your if needs an else that outputs the letter and count and resets the count

Comment: In case you provide `aabccc` as input, would you like to get `a2b1c3` or `a2bc3` as output?

Answer (score 1):

Use two loops. Use an outer while to loop the string. Whenever a new letter is encountered, use the for loop to increment count as the long as the letters belong to the same sequence. When done increment the outer counter (`i`) to get to the next letter:

```js
var countLetters = "aaabbccccddd";
var result = '';
var i = 0;

while (i < countLetters.length) {
  // iterate until current letter, and counted letter are not equal, increment count
  for (var count = 1; countLetters[i] === countLetters[i + count]; count++) {}

  // add current letter and count to string
  result += countLetters[i] + count;

  i += count; // increment outer counter - i
}

console.log(result);
```

Another solution that uses a [`String.match()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) with a regex to get an array of letter sequences. Then [maps](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) each sequence to letter + count, and [joins](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) them back to a string:

```js
var countLetters = "aaabbccccddd";

var result = countLetters.match(/(\w)\1+/g) // match sequences of the same letter
  .map((s) => s[0] + s.length) // map each sequence to letter with count
  .join(''); // join back to a string

console.log(result);
```

Comment: hey can you give comments...it will help to understand better and in future I can fix it myself

Answer (score 0):

```
var hashMap = {};
var countLetters = "aaabbccccddd";
countLetters.split("").forEach((letter) => {
    if(!hashMap[letter]) {
        hashMap[letter] = 0;
    }
    hashMap[letter] = hashMap[letter]+1;
})
var string ='';
for(var i in hashMap) {
    var val = hashMap[i];
    string += i + val;
}

console.log("countNumberLetter--------->",string);
```

Comment: hey can you give comments...it will help to understand better and in future I can fix it myself

Answer (score 0):

```
const object = {};
const string = "aaabbccccddd";

// To iterate over string
for(let i = 0; i < string.length; i++){
    // if the object has that alphabet just increment it 
    if(object.hasOwnProperty(string.charAt(i))){   
        ++object[string.charAt(i)]; 
    }else{
        // else create a key to the new alphabet and give it a value 1
        object[string.charAt(i)] = 1;
    }
}

let finalString = "";

// To iterate over the object
for(let key in object){
    finalString += key;  // concatenate the key  
    finalString += object[key];  // concatenate the value 
} 

console.log(finalString);
```

My solution has two loops one to iterate over the string and store the alphabet and there count in an object ( you can use hashmap as well ). 
The 2nd loop is to iterate over object so that we can make the desired string.

Comment: hey can you give comments...it will help to understand better and in future I can fix it myself